# Why does my site load slowly after enabling SSL in .htaccess?

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, page-load-time

I have a site developed in [CodeIgniter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeIgniter) and after enabling SSL redirection, it started to load very slowly. I am using this for my redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://visualimpacteastwest.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated .

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, probably look at [su], [sf], or [webmasters.se]. But before posting you will need to improve the "it started to load very slowly" as this is not a scientific observation. Run any kind of tool, including those in your browsers to really understand what is taking time (it may not be related to TLS). Look also at your server logfiles for clues.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. Give a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In your codeigniter application config file get the base url to blank:

*/application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
```

Comment: How would that change any kind of "speed" observations the OP has? Both code snippets do basically the same thing, do you have data that shows, for a given website, different speed with your configuration from the OP configuration?

Comment: Thats true, it didn't really change the loadtime. I think the way CodeIgniter handles the request is the issue, or it could be the hosting as well but its so odd such a simple things brings down speed like that, is there any other solution?